# Braintreepayment: Merchant is not set up to accept PayPal

Tags: php, android, paypal, braintree

I am just going through the Braintreepayments "Get Started" [page](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/android+php/start/overview). This is a very simple tutorial. A few lines of code in both client and server, in my case Android and PHP. Basically, my codes are same as per tutorial.

I am getting unexpected exception thrown as following.

> com.braintreepayments.api.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Merchant is not setup to accept PayPal

[image: Logcat error log]

In the control panel, PayPal is enabled by default in the Sandbox.

[image: Braintree Sanbox control panel]

But I could not find the place to enter Paypal Sandbox Merchant Account as explained in this doc. Probably, this document does not cover for sandbox.

[image: Braintree Setup Guide]

Can anyone please point me out if there is any steps or doc I missed out to check?

Comment: Is the error coming from the Braintree sandbox or was it submitted to production?

Comment: This is from sandbox

Answer (score 3):

@Sithu Your sandbox was created outside supported country, which is not a supported country with PayPal that's why you are getting error "Merchant is not set up to accept PayPal".

**Example:**
If you are a developer working for a US based merchant on an integration, you will need to signup as a US based braintree sandbox account. You can do this on BrainTree website by selecting United States as your country using the drop-down menu on the bottom left of the page.

Remember: bottom left of signup page >> Select Country as US

I signed up for another sandbox account on BrainTree using US as my country and it worked perfectly.

After signup, got to **Settings** >> **Processing** and check "**Accepted Payment Methods**" list, you will see a "paypal" icon there that's means your account support paypal payment method.[image]

Answer (score 2):

After Braintree support team has enabled the Paypal as a processor connection for my sandbox, I am able to continue the to make the payment with Paypal.

[image: Braintree support team reply]

I sent further question, why Paypal is not default enabled as a processor connection in my Sandbox. Below is support team reply.

[image: Braintree Reply]

I was wondering how to join Paypal sandbox accounts in Braintree. According to Braintree support team reply, this is not possible. Braintree is a separate and an entirely enclosed environment.

[image]